# How to Think in terms of Object Oriented Programming?

Tags: oop

i've been interested in game programming for a while and tried to read quite a lot of books on OOP. The problem is for the most part the books show you code and say "add this here" "add this there" but they fail to explain "the big picture" of OOP instead of jumping around. What i want to know i how to think in terms of OOP. For example i've read this thread [Object Oriented application problems in game development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962074/object-oriented-application-problems-in-game-development) which gives you some good insight on howto THINK about your classes (like, player "has", "can"....world "listens"). What i would like some help with is a way of thinking, to make the right questions order to plan well which things should be left for a "player class" to do, which things to leave for the "world class" to do, which things to make "private" and which to leave "public", etc. I want to answer the "Why" not the "Hows" I don't want the code, i want the Questions or Mind Set for OOP to become a natural way to organize code.

For example, if i am dealing with collision detection. Should i leave this for the "world" to check?, should i leave it for the player to check? Which question should i ask myself?

Sorry for the "broad" question, but anything would help. From a good "book" to some tips.

PD: I do not have mucho programming experience

Best regards,

Comment: Dont be sorry for the "broad" question. This is a good question. However, if you do not have much programming experience i found it easier to learn programming from a non-OO point of view then work my way there. I believe it best to learn a language first then learn OOP. Just my opinion.

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Object-Oriented-Thought-Process-3rd/dp/0672330164/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1296849133&sr=1-1

Comment: This isn't a great question for SO. However I think you could rephrase it to make it a **much** better question: ask your collision detection question. I think that question gets straight to the heart of the matter using a concrete example as a means to understand the OOP thought process. Then again, there are already [some questions on this](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=oop+game+object+collision)!

Comment: I think more programming experience will go hand in hand with books about thinking in objects. As you gain a better understanding of programming, I think it will become easier for you to organize your projects into objects.

Comment: @matt there are a lot of general questions on SO. sometimes marked community wiki

Answer (score 2):

Stop reading books and get out there and program.  Learn Java.  Use a book to do it, but don't just go through the motions, don't download the code write it yourself.  In the beginning you will wonder what is the point of OOP, but then you will get into more complex problems and you will start to appreciate the freedom that OOP gives you.  Things like inheritance, encapsulation, and polymorphism are just terms right now for you.  You kinda know what they mean but you haven't programmed enough to use the concepts.  Once you use them and make classes that exemplify the concepts then you start to learn real object oriented programming.  You shouldn't focus on making your game OOP, you should focus on making OOP fit your game.

So moral of the story is go program.

Answer (score 1):

Write, write software. People make too big of a deal out of OOP. It's merely an approach to achieve certain design principals such as modularity and low coupling. You experiment and see what makes code - good code, how to make code flexible and maintainable. then you will understand the principles that lead to a good design, whether purely functional, procedural, OOP, or any other paradigm.

Answer (score 1):

I think the key to learning OOP is indeed writing code, but start to think in terms of how you would model the real world - i.e., a car object has attributes of doors, tires, engine, and so on, while the behaviors would be perhaps start engine, change oil, ect....free your mind and think of things in a method that will relate to how you can make writing code less cumbersome and complex. Some problems are inherintly complex, but OOP can help you to sort it out and think of things in a real world fashion. You can do it...just start trying....

Answer (score 0):

I read earlier edition of "Object-Oriented Thought Process" and found the book immensely helpful in understanding the whole OOP paradigm.

[http://www.amazon.com/Object-Oriented-Thought-Process-3rd/dp/0672330164/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672330164)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best way to 'grock' the concept of Object Oriented Programming is to think of code as modules, or building blocks - write code so it can be modularized in this fashion, then you can reuse them whenever you need that code by simply calling them as needed instead of writing the same code over and over and over again.  It's as much a discipline as well as a taught subject.  It is also helpful to document your code so when you go back later to reuse it - you know what kind of arguments it takes, what kind of output it generates, and how it does what you wrote it to do.

Answer (score 0):

As you have said, this is a very broad question. With experience, you will have a better sense of when to use what.

While it is nice to know the "whys", remember that knowing the "hows" builds a good foundation for you to understand the "whys".

Now, to answer the specific ones that you have brought up. Think of public as something you would put in the API. If you have a "player class", what do you want the rest of your code to do with it? You want to interact with it in some sense. What is the interface to interact with the "player class"? Those that are your interface should be "public".

So what are the things that should be private? For example, if there is some attribute to the player class that has to be in a valid range (let's say between 1 to 100). How do you prevent people (other parts of the code) from corrupting that? You use private for that. This prevents other people from setting the value to 1001. This way, if it ever gets into a bad state, you know it's the class that screwed up, not the rest of the code.

As for designs, remember that designs change. When you first set out with your program, you may decide the one class should do the collision detection. (That is, your "world" has a collision detector) Maybe at first you just write your "world" with the collision detector. And later on you refactored the code out and have a class called "Collision detector". Then later on you may decide it goes somewhere else, but it's easy since you can just have another object to "have a" Collision detector.

Point is, if you make your code modular enough, this will be easy. There are no hard rules. You first write your code with the design you have in mind. Along the way you are going to find better ways of doing things.

Comment: Thanks all for the help. I will take a look at the book you mentioned, it looks interestnig, buyt mainly....code, code and code till it makes sense!